# Print stacktrace of a function from a goroutine

Tags: multithreading, go, operating-system, stack-trace, goroutine

I have a function that is 1/1000 times getting stuck somewhere and I want to figure out where it gets frozen. This unfortunately only happens in production. I want to print the stacktrace of this function by analyzing whether it has been running for 30 mins or not.

The logic I thought of is something like this:

```
func funcToWatch(){
   go monitor()
   doSomeOtherwork()
}

func monitor(){
   time.Sleep(time.Minute*30)
   printStackTraceOffuncToWatch()
}
```

I can't find out how to print the stacktrace of this function from its monitoring function inside another goroutine. Any ideas?

One thing is to print all the stacktraces of all the goroutines but there are simply too many concurrent tasks that I'll be unable to figure out which one is stuck.

Comment: "I can't find out how to print the stacktrace of this function from its monitoring function inside another goroutine." As this is not possible (that's not how stacks work) it is understandable that you didn't find a way to do so. "Any ideas?" Come up with an other way to debug that problem.

Comment: @Volker could you please elaborate on "that's not how stacks work"? Still in the process of learning, so would appreciate any reading material/blog etc.

Comment: There’s 2 issues, you can only unwind your own stack, and individual goroutines are not addressable. If there’s too many stacks to visually inspect, write some simple code to filter out the one you want. Other options are to use a debugger or instrument the goroutine to dump its own stack trace as you narrow down where it gets stuck.

Comment: Stacks grow naturally only in one direction: In any function you know the caller. When funcToWatch calls calls `go monitor` the stack splits and one part grows with monitor and the other grows with doSomeOtherwork. From monitor you can go down the stack reaching funcToWatch and further to any function that did call funcToWatch but there is no information in funcToWatch that there are several stacks forking upwards. (As this information would have to life on the stack but is unbound in size this is basically undoable.)